# Thymeleaf th:each filtered with th:if

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to iterate and create `<span>` elements for each of the `component` in the `components` array which has the `name` of `'MATERIAL'`

**My code is as below**

```html
<span th:each="component : ${body.components}" 
      th:object="${component}">
        <button th:if="*{name} == 'MATERIAL'" 
                th:text="*{title}"></button>
</span>
```

This code works all good until this produces a set of empty `<span>` elements if the `name` is not equal to `'MATERIAL'`. I don't want this empty `<span>` elements to get created.

**I also tried the below**

```html
<span th:each="component : ${body.components}" 
      th:object="${component}"
      th:if="*{name} == 'MATERIAL'">
         <button th:text="*{title}"></button>
</span>
```

This results in empty output and doesn't print anything at all. Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should reference the iteration item property directly using a dot (**.**) sign instead of going through an SpEL expression evalution (`*{name}`) inside your  html element:

```html
<span th:each="component : ${body.components}" 
      th:object="${component}"
      th:if="${component.name} == 'MATERIAL'">
  <button th:text="*{title}"></button>
</span>
```